# Change BG colour

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I can't change the colour of the frame area..

CODE::

```py
import time
import threading
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Text
import os

class PomodoroTimer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("2400x1400")
        #3024 × 1964
        self.root.title("Focus")
        self.root.tk_setPalette(background='#85BB65', foreground='#85BB65')

        self.tabs = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.tabs.pack(fill="both", pady=10, expand=True)



        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure("TFrame", background="#004B49")
        self.style.configure("TLabel", foreground="#bfe0f2")
        self.style.configure("TButton", background="#bfe0f2", foreground="#85BB65")
        self.style.configure("TNotebook.Tab", background="#1dcfb1", foreground="#85BB65")
        self.style.configure("TNotebook", background="#1dcfb1")
        self.style.configure("TNotebook.Tab", padding=[30, 5])

        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabs, style="TFrame")
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabs, style="TFrame")
        self.tab3 = ttk.Frame(self.tabs, style="TFrame")

        self.pomodoro_timer_label = ttk.Label(self.tab1, text="25:00", font=("impact", 200), style="TLabel")
        self.pomodoro_short_break_label = ttk.Label(self.tab2, text="05:00", font=("impact", 200), style="TLabel")
        self.pomodoro_long_break_label = ttk.Label(self.tab3, text="15:00", font=("impact", 200), style="TLabel")

        self.pomodoro_timer_label.pack(pady=20)
        self.pomodoro_short_break_label.pack(pady=20)
        self.pomodoro_long_break_label.pack(pady=20)

        self.tabs.add(self.tab1, text="Pomodoro")
        self.tabs.add(self.tab2, text="Short Break")
        self.tabs.add(self.tab3, text="Long Break")

        self.grid_layout = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        self.grid_layout.pack(pady=10)

        self.start_button = ttk.Button(self.grid_layout, text="Start", command=self.start_timer_thread, style="TButton")
        self.skip_button = ttk.Button(self.grid_layout, text="Skip", command=self.skip_clock, style="TButton")
        self.reset_button = ttk.Button(self.grid_layout, text="Reset", command=self.reset_clock, style="TButton")
        self.open_note_button = ttk.Button(self.grid_layout, text="Open Note", command=self.open_note, style="TButton")
        self.open_calculator_button = ttk.Button(self.grid_layout, text="Open Calculator", command=self.op_calc, style="TButton")

        self.start_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
        self.skip_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
        self.reset_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5)
        self.open_note_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5)
        self.open_calculator_button.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=5)

        self.pomodoro_counter_label = ttk.Label(self.grid_layout, text="Pomodoros: 0", font=("impact", 60), style="TLabel")
        self.pomodoro_counter_label.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, column=0)

        self.pomodoros = 0
        self.skipped = False
        self.stopped = False
        self.current_timer = None

        self.note_window = None
        self.note_text = None
        self.note_file = "note.txt"

        if os.path.exists(self.note_file):
            with open(self.note_file, "r") as file:
                self.note_text = file.read()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def start_timer_thread(self):
        if self.current_timer is None or not self.current_timer.is_alive():
            self.current_timer = threading.Thread(target=self.start_timer)
            self.current_timer.start()

    def start_timer(self):
        self.stopped = False
        self.skipped = False
        timer_id = self.tabs.index(self.tabs.select()) + 1

        if timer_id == 1:
            full_seconds = 60 * 25
            label = self.pomodoro_timer_label
        elif timer_id == 2:
            full_seconds = 60 * 5
            label = self.pomodoro_short_break_label
        elif timer_id == 3:
            full_seconds = 60 * 15
            label = self.pomodoro_long_break_label
        else:
            print("Invalid timer id")
            return

        while full_seconds > 0 and not self.stopped:
            minutes, seconds = divmod(full_seconds, 60)
            label.config(text=f"{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}")
            self.root.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            full_seconds -= 1

        if not self.stopped or self.skipped:
            self.pomodoros += 1
            self.pomodoro_counter_label.config(text=f"Pomodoros: {self.pomodoros}")

            if self.pomodoros % 4 == 0:
                self.tabs.select(2)
            else:
                self.tabs.select(0)

            self.current_timer = None
            self.start_timer()

    def reset_clock(self):
        self.stopped = True
        self.skipped = False
        timer_id = self.tabs.index(self.tabs.select()) + 1
        if timer_id == 1:
            self.pomodoro_timer_label.config(text="25:00")
        elif timer_id == 2:
            self.pomodoro_short_break_label.config(text="05:00")
        elif timer_id == 3:
            self.pomodoro_long_break_label.config(text="15:00")

    def skip_clock(self):
        self.stopped = True
        self.skipped = True
        timer_id = self.tabs.index(self.tabs.select()) + 1
        if timer_id == 1:
            self.pomodoros += 1
            self.pomodoro_counter_label.config(text=f"Pomodoros: {self.pomodoros}")
        self.tabs.select(0)
        self.start_timer()

    def open_note(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("NOTES")
        window.geometry("1000x700")

        note_entry = tk.Text(window)
        note_entry.pack()

        def save_note():
            note = note_entry.get("1.0", tk.END)
            conn = sqlite3.connect("notes.db")
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, content TEXT)")
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO notes (content) VALUES (?)", (note,))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

        save_button = tk.Button(window, text="Save Note", command=save_note,foreground="#85BB65",font="Impact")
        save_button.pack()

        def view_notes():
            conn = sqlite3.connect("notes.db")
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM notes")
            notes = cursor.fetchall()
            conn.close()

            view_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
            view_window.title("View Notes")
            view_text = tk.Text(view_window)
            for note in notes:
                view_text.insert(tk.END, note[1] + "\n")
            view_text.pack()

        view_button = tk.Button(window, text="View Notes", command=view_notes,foreground="#85BB65",font="Impact")
        view_button.pack()

    def op_calc(self):
        # pip install tkinter
        import tkinter as tk
        import tkinter.messagebox
        from tkinter.constants import SUNKEN

        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title('Calculator')
        frame = tk.Frame(master=window, bg="#85BB65", padx=10)
        frame.pack()
        entry = tk.Entry(master=frame, relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=3, width=30)
        entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, ipady=2, pady=2)

        def myclick(number):
            entry.insert(tk.END, number)

        def equal():
            try:
                y = str(eval(entry.get()))
                entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                entry.insert(0, y)
            except:
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Syntax Error")

        def clear():
            entry.delete(0, tk.END)

        button_1 = tk.Button(master=frame, text='1', padx=15,
                             pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick(1))
        button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2)
        button_2 = tk.Button(master=frame, text='2', padx=15,
                             pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick(2))
        button_2.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2)
        button_3 = tk.Button(master=frame, text='3', padx=15,
                             pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick(3))
        button_3.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=2)
        button_4 = tk.Button(master=frame, text='4', padx=15,
                             pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick(4))
        button_4.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2)
        button_5 = tk.Button(master=frame, text='5', padx=15,
                             pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick(5))
        button_5.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=2)
        button_6 = tk.Button(master=frame, text='6', padx=15,
                             pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick(6))
        button_6.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=2)
        button_7 = tk.Button(master=frame, text='7', padx=15,
                             pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick(7))
        button_7.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2)
        button_8 = tk.Button(master=frame, text='8', padx=15,
                             pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick(8))
        button_8.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=2)
        button_9 = tk.Button(master=frame, text='9', padx=15,
                             pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick(9))
        button_9.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=2)
        button_0 = tk.Button(master=frame, text='0', padx=15,
                             pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick(0))
        button_0.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=2)

        button_add = tk.Button(master=frame, text="+", padx=15,
                               pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick('+'))
        button_add.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=2)

        button_subtract = tk.Button(
            master=frame, text="-", padx=15, pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick('-'))
        button_subtract.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=2)

        button_multiply = tk.Button(
            master=frame, text="*", padx=15, pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick('*'))
        button_multiply.grid(row=5, column=2, pady=2)

        button_div = tk.Button(master=frame, text="/", padx=15,
                               pady=5, width=3, command=lambda: myclick('/'))
        button_div.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=2)

        button_clear = tk.Button(master=frame, text="clear",
                                 padx=15, pady=5, width=12, command=clear)
        button_clear.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=2)

        button_equal = tk.Button(master=frame, text="=", padx=15,
                                 pady=5, width=9, command=equal)
        button_equal.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=2)

        window.mainloop()
```

The marked area is the colour I want to change the colour of. (I have marked it with black pen) [image]

I Just want to change the colour.

Comment: Is there another instance of `Tk()` created when creating instance of `PomodoroTimer`?  Try changing `self.style = ttk.Style()` to `self.style = ttk.Style(master=self.root)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have several instances of Tk(), which may cause problems.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()

def open_note(self):
    window = tk.Tk()

def op_calc(self):
    window = tk.Tk()
```

See [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged/48045508#48045508)

> Each Tcl interpreter is an isolated sandbox. An object in one sandbox cannot interact with objects in another. The most common manifestation of that is that a StringVar created in one interpreter is not visible in another. The same goes for widgets -- you can't create widgets in one interpreter that has as a parent widget in another interpreter. Images are a third case: images created in one cannot be used in another.

Also see this discussion of application structure: [What is the best way to structure a Tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/what-is-the-best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application/17470842#17470842)

Hope this may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't change the colour of the frame area..

Use variable then prefix. You can use any variable name, but don't use the same variable for each `Frame`.

Change this on line 23:

```
self.style.configure("TFrame", background="red")
```

to:

```
self.style.configure("My.TFrame", background="red") #Add variable
```

Change this on line 31:

```
self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabs, style="TFrame")
```

to:

```
self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabs, style="My.TFrame")
```

Screenshot:

[image]